# circumvent default servlet java

Tags: java, xml, servlets, webserver, jetty

My problem is that all request go through default servlet, like this:

```
DefaultServlet defaultServlet = new DefaultServlet();
ServletHolder holder = new ServletHolder(defaultServlet);
context.addServlet(holder, "/");
```

But for concrete requests I need to have another mappings. How can I do that?
For example, `"/anotherMapping/"` should not go through `DefaultServlet`.
How can I do that using java `import org.eclipse.jetty.*` and not changing `xml` file?

Answer (score 1):

The mapping is a rules engine with a cascading priority.

If you put the default as the last one, you should be fine.

eg.

```
 context.addServlet(...., "/anotherMapping/*");
 context.addServlet(...., "/*")
```

Comment: yes, and order shouldn't really matter either, the 'best' match is the one that will be called